# How to get two rows in ListView.separated

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to achieve the following output but instead of one row in a column, I want to show two rows in a column using `ListView.separated`. How can I get it? `ListView.separated` does not have any option to display 2 rows.

```
Scaffold(
          body: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return Container(
                height: 40.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text('Your text goes here'),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, position) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('Divider'),
              );
            },
            itemCount: 20,
          ),
        ));
```

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far? can you please share the code

Comment: i wanted to achive this with ads between them -[link]( https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRFNRlDwgKktsr5PVB-CfgGrSuHP3T2qh7bkGAk3aDEXZf9E20Q&usqp=CAU)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use the `Row` widget. In order to expand the `Text` widgets, you can wrap them with `Expanded`.

Full working example, based on your code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return Container(
              height: 40.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Text('Your text goes here'),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, position) {
            return Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(
                      'Divider 1',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(
                      'Divider 2',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          itemCount: 20,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```